# Determine where the function is differentiable

Tags: derivatives

I have to determine where the function 
$$
f:x \mapsto \arccos \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$
is differentiable. For $ x = 0$ we have $\arccos (1) = 0$ so would f be differentiable in the interval from $[-1,1[$?

Comment: Try taking the general derivative. The points where the derivative does not exist, are the points where it is non-derivable.

Comment: I think it should be not derivable at x = 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hat it is differentiable on the open interval $(-1,1)$.

Now, as  $\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$  is differentiable on $\mathbf R$, the condition would  be $-1 < \frac 1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}< 1$, but as it is positive for all $x$, this condition reduces to
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}\ne 1\iff x\ne 0.$$